# Choked flow through pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I am trying to figure what the minimum diameter for a fuel pipe would be. How would I calculate the minimum diameter for the pipe to be so that flow is not choked?

The pipe would take fuel from a fuel pump (as in from a petrol station) to the fuel tank in the vehicle.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A practical recommendation: don't exceed a fluid velocity of 10 feet/second, as flows higher than this produce a LOT of pressure drop.